# Codeigniter - How to populate form from database?

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter

I have a small site which allows a user to enter values in a form and then either submit it directly or store the field values in a template to later submit it. To submit the form later, he can load the previously saved template. For that there are three buttons **Load Template** / **Save Template** / **Submit form**.

Because i am using the form validation built-in functionality from Codeigniter i run into problems when i want to populate the form with a template, which had been previously stored.

The form fields are all set up like

```
$name = array(
'name'  => 'name',
'id'    => 'name',
'value' => set_value('name', $form_field_values['name'])
);
```

The variable `$form_field_values` holds the values from either a loaded template in the case when a template has been loaded or the default values when the form is first loaded.

Initially the form is loaded with the default values. When i click on **Load Template** the values from the template are not chosen by `set_value()` because there were the default values in there before. What i want is **to replace the values of the form fields with the ones from the template**.

Do you have any idea how to do that in a clean approach? What i have done is to introduce a variable to skip the call to `set_value()` completely like:

```
$name= array(
'name'  => 'name',
'id'    => 'name',
'value' => $skip_form_validation ? $form_field_values['name'] : set_value('name', $form_field_values['name'])
);
```

Where `$skip_form_validation` is a variable set in the controller, based on what button was pressed. Form validation is skipped for saving/loading a template.

Comment: What you're doing is fine, I just wrote an answer saying you don't really need the skip form validation but I read again and you're using it for your controller as well. This is a good approach, if all you're asking is if there is a better way to do it the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter's set_value() function is a simple function which finds value in $_POST if value found then return else returns second argument, you can remove set_value() and write your own code for it. you can write $_POST['field_name'] if you want to populate value of POST data or add whatever value you want to add
Just use like this

```
$name = array(
    'name'  => 'name',
    'id'    => 'name',
    'value' => $valueFromYourTemplate
);
```

You don't need to use set_value() function if you don't want to set POST values in the form

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you retrieve the database fields and pass them to a data array in your controller.

```
$record = $this->data_model->get_record(array('uid' => $user_id), 'users');

if (!is_null($record)) {

   $data['uname'] = $record->username;

   $data['loc'] = $record->location;
}
```

where 'users' is the database table, and the uid is the id field of the table users.

In your form, do something like this

Hope it helps!